# time complexity of variable loops

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

i want to try to calculate the O(n) of my program (in python). there are two problems:

1: i have a very basic knowledge of O(n) [aka: i know O(n) has to do with time and calculations]

and

2: all of the loops in my program are not set to any particular value. they are based on the input data.

Comment: That's exactly what the N means in big-oh notation (what you're calling O(n)). The N stands for the size of the input. It depends on the problem. Maybe you can share some more context?

Comment: Your second "problem" is not a problem, which you would know if you solved your first problem. I think you should do some basic study first and then come back if you have some more specific questions.

Comment: Indeed. If there was no recursion and all loops were a constant number of iterations, the time complexity would be O(1).

Comment: Haha you cracked me up!
Thank you for that!

Answer (score 4):

The `n` in `O(n)` means precisely the input size. So, if I have this code:

```
def findmax(l):
    maybemax = 0
    for i in l:
        if i > maybemax:
            maybemax = i
    return maybemax
```

Then I'd say that the complexity is `O(n)` -- how long it takes is proportional to the input size (since the loop loops as many times as the length of `l`).

If I had

```
def allbigger(l, m):
    for el in l:
        for el2 in m:
            if el < el2:
                return False
    return True
```

then, in the worst case (that is, when I return `True`), I have one loop of length `len(l)` and inside it, one of length `len(m)`, so I say that it's `O(l * m)` or `O(n^2)` if the lists are expected to be about the same length.

Comment: You just have to be aware of how long function calls in your loop take and factor them in. For instance `for i in range(n): if i in arr: do something` Is actually O(N^2) and not O(N) since the in operator takes O(N) time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out to start, then head to wiki:

- [Plain English Explanation of Big O Notation](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/07/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o.html)